# How to delete hasmany relation data in laravel

Tags: laravel, function, relation, geotargetting

How can i delete Hasmany relation data.One more think i want to delete only has_student data.

$user->has_student->delete();

Error:
Collection doesn't has delete method.

Comment: How about `has_student()->delete()` ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to detach your relationships to delete them.

```php
$user->has_student()->detach(); // remove every instance of relationship

$user->has_student()->detach([array of has_student]); // remove selected relationship
```

You can follow the more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user->has_student()->delete();
```

Here in

```
$user=User::find(your_desire_id);
```